# Creating and re-filling a hole inside existing Delaunay tetrahedralization

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, mesh, cgal

I am trying to implement a [mesh generation algorithm](http://www.imr.sandia.gov/papers/imr14/si.pdf). I am representing Delaunay tetrahedralization using `CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3` class.

In one stage of the algorithm(section 7: Facet recovery), I have a Delaunay tetrahedralization(say `DT0`), I need to create a cavity(or hole)`C` inside the Delaunay tetrahedralization(thereby transforming it to say `DT1`) and fill it again with new tetrahedrons by performing Delaunay tetrahedralization(say `DT2`) on the vertices of the cavity. Resulting tetrahedralization need not be *purely* Delaunay(i.e, it may have some cells not satisfying [*empty sphere* criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)). More details on why such cavity needs to be created and refilled again are mentioned below in the **context** section.

**Question:**
Is it possible in CGAL to create such a cavity inside an *existing* Delaunay tetrahedralization and fill it with another tetrahedralization?

**Relevent details:**

- Cavity `C` is a polyhedron with all of its facets shared with that of cells in `DT0`.
- `DT2` does not represent complete Delaunay tetrahedralization of vertices of `C`. It  contains only those tetrahedrons which are inside `C`, rest of the tetrahedrons are discarded.
- I find [this question](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/How-to-do-Delaunay-tetrahedralization-for-several-triangulated-surfaces-td3317165.html) to be
  *somewhat* related to mine but that is still unsolved.

**Context:**
The purpose for creating the cavity and refilling it is the following:
Algorithm(mentioned above) is for computing a *constraint preserving* Delaunay tetrahedralization. Input to the algorithm is a set of vertices,segments(a segment connects 2 vertices) and facets(in my case these are triangles) given as constraints that must be preserved in the final tetrahedralization. In this question, I am discussing about implementation of *facet preservation* part of the algorithm. To *recover* any missing constraint facet in the final tetrahedralization, algorithm creates a cavity and refills it with tetrahedrons(or cells) in such way that combination of the facets of some of these cells recover the constraint facet(i.e., `f1+f2+...+fn=f` where `f1,f2..fn` are facets of some newly created cells in the cavity and `f` is the constraint facet, or in other words, `f1,f2..fn` are sub-facets of `f`) in the output tetrahedralization. Output tetrahedralization is called *Constrained Delaunay tetrahedralization* in literature and it may or may not be *Delaunay*.

**My attempt:**
Currently, I do not find any relevant CGAL class to directly solve this issue so I am thinking of doing the following:

1. Representing initial Delaunay tetrahedralization `DT0` using `CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3`.
2. Computing cavity `C` inside `DT0` following the algorithm and representing `C` as a separate `Polyhedron_3` object. Remaining set of tetrahedrons are collectively denoted by `DT1`.
3. Computing Delaunay tetrahedralization `DT2'` of the vertices of `C`.
4. Selecting cells from `DT2'`(as per algorithm) to compute `DT2`.
5. Finally, merging `DT1` and `DT2`. Since both share facets of `C`(guaranteed by the algorithm), so they can be connected in principle.

Right now I am thinking of representing `DT1` and `DT2` as `std::list<Tetrahedron_3>` object but how to merge them to create a tetrahedralization?

Comment: Ahhh digging holes and then filling them again... A well known practice among software developers

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have added **context** section to my original question. I hope it will explain the purpose of creating and re-filling the cavity.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way that the point removal is implemented in CGAL.
You may want to look at the code for remove.

Comment: I understand that a cavity will be created when a vertex is removed from tetrahedralization and will be _effectively_ filled again by re-tetrahedralization of the remaining entire vertex set. But in my case(as I have now mentioned in **context**), I need to preserve some facets as well. I suspect that vertex removal procedure may not be able to guarantee this. Further, I want that remaining part of the original tetrahedralization(i.e., the cells outside cavity) to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

After reading CGAL documentation, I realized that I can represent my output mesh in form of [Linear cell complex](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Linear_cell_complex/index.html) instead. I can now do the following:

1. Import my original Delaunay tetrahedralization to Linear cell complex format using [`import_from_triangulation_3()`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Linear_cell_complex/group__PkgLinearCellComplexConstructions.html#ga7e8cde514b93c3441a4df2bc09c24068).
2. Create cavity inside it by applying the algorithm and using [`remove_cell()`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/group__PkgCombinatorialMapsOperations.html#gab70174b3358188a92dd3a0a054d02e42).
3. Filling the cavity with the Delaunay tetrahedralization of vertices of the cavity(as per algorithm) and adding these new cells to the original tetrahedral mesh using `sew3_same_facets()`(undocumented function). I have got reference for `sew3_same_facets()` from [CGAL discussion forum](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Implementing-tetrahedral-mesh-with-cavities-using-Linear-cell-complex-td4659399.html).

Right now, I am not accepting my response as the answer since I am still in process of implementing it. But I thought of sharing it meanwhile.